# Angular 2.2 and ng-bootstrap Cannot read property 'Observable' of undefined

Tags: angular, angular-cli, ng-bootstrap

I've reported this issue on [Github](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues/1104), but asking it here won't hurt either

Bug description:

I added in ng-bootstrap and started getting this error.

```
VM325:9 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Observable' of undefined(…)webpackUniversalModuleDefinition @ VM325:9(anonymous function) @ VM325:10module.exports @ scripts.bundle.js:28476 @ scripts.bundle.js:6__webpack_require__ @ inline.bundle.js:53826 @ scripts.bundle.js:37__webpack_require__ @ inline.bundle.js:53webpackJsonpCallback @ inline.bundle.js:24(anonymous function) @ scripts.bundle.js:1 main.bundle.js:420
```

Link to minimally-working plunker that reproduces the issue:

Please see [my GitHub branch](https://github.com/aligneddev/JQueryToAurelia/tree/angular).

This commit does not have this error 4a049710ba900f5aef8d11141491607e45e49cc2.
This commit [fcf8260c8b560f665fc4a34b49dd47f1700c3945](https://github.com/aligneddev/JQueryToAurelia/commit/fcf8260c8b560f665fc4a34b49dd47f1700c3945) 'bring in bootstrap - couldn't get js include without observable of undefined error' introduced the error.

Version of Angular, ng-bootstrap, and Bootstrap:

Angular 2.2 - CLI

ng-bootstrap: "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-alpha.14",

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just cloned your repo, you need to do 3 changes on different files, I'm going to explain each one.

### package.json

You forgot to add the bootstrap dependency, when I cloned your repo I got errors due to the missing package, just do:

```
npm i bootstrap@next --save
```

Or add `"bootstrap": "^4.0.0-alpha.5"` into your dependencies list.

### src/app/app.component.html

You don't have a router-outlet on your main component, without that your routes will never work, change your **app.component.html** into this:

```
<h1>Energy with Angular 2.0</h1>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Your **EnergyComponent** will be injected inside the `<router-outlet>` by angular.

### angular-cli.json

Last but not least your main problem, the Observable error is due to the fact you are including **ng-bootstrap** on your `scripts`, just remove that line, it should look something like this:

```
"styles": [
  "styles.css",
  "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"
],
"scripts": [],
```

Why? Because you are already including **ng-boostrap** when you import it on your **app.module.ts** you only add scripts when they are an external dependencies, but you don't use them directly on your code. For example if you were using the pure boostrap way, css + javascript/jquery you would add the **bootstrap.js** on your **scripts** array